# VLC: How can I see what I'm recording?

Tags: command-line, windows-10, vlc

On Windows 10 I use a batch to open the webcam and start a recording. But while it is recording, the VLC interface shows black.
How can I see what is being recorded at the same time on the VLC screen?
This is the command line:

```
vlc -Idummy -vvv dshow:// :dshow-vdev="myWebCam" :dshow-adev :live-caching=300 --sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=512}:std{access=file,dst="miVideo.mp4"}
```

I have tried the following, but the interface appears black:

```
vlc  dshow:// :dshow-vdev="myWebCam" :dshow-adev :live-caching=300 --sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=512}:std{access=file,dst="miVideo.mp4"}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! This is the solution:

```
vlc dshow:// :dshow-vdev="myWebCam" :dshow-adev :live-caching=300 --sout=#duplicate{dst=display,dst=transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=512}}:std{access=file,dst=C:\myVideo.mp4"}
```